# 3 middleware functions with a try catch block not stopping app from crashing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I need to stop my app from crashing and just res.send the error to me but its not working look.

my routes:

```
router.post('/signUp',signupmiddlewere.signup2error,Routes.signUp)
router.post('/login',Routes.login)
router.post('/jwtverify',Routes.jwtverify)
router.use(errormiddelware)
router.use(usererrorFunction)
router.use(regularerrorFunction)
```

my route that can give an error:

```
module.exports.jwtverify = async (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        const {jwt} = req.body
        
        let objectid = 1

        JWT.verify(jwt, 'secret', function(err, decoded) {
            objectid = decoded.id._id
        });

        let user = 0  

        await User.findOne({_id:objectid}).then((result)=>{
            user = result
        }).catch((err)=>{
            next(err)
        })

        res.status(200).send({
            status:'success',
            user:user
        })

    } catch (error) {
        next(error) 
    }
}
```

here is my 3 error middleweres:
1:

```
const regularerrorFunction = (error,req,res,next)=>{
    return res.json(error.message)
}

module.exports = regularerrorFunction
```

2. 

```
const errorFunction = (error,req,res,next)=>{
    return res.status(500).json(error.message)
}

module.exports = errorFunction
```

3. 

```
const usererrorFunction = (error,req,res,next)=>{
    return res.status(400).json(error.message)
}

module.exports = usererrorFunction
```

I use both of them at the bottom like stack told me too. There are 3 functions that use status 400,500 and just a regular error. I use a try catch block. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is that the way you're using `JWT.verify()` is asynchronous, but you are not coding it that way.  You are assuming its synchronous.

You have no error handling for `JWT.verify(jwt, 'secret', function(err, decoded) { ... })`.  You should promisify that and then let `await` and the `try/catch` work for you.  Also, remove the `.catch()` so the `try/catch` can do its work.  And, get rid of the `.then()` (use the `await` only).

```
const JWT.verifyP = util.promisify(JWT.verify);

module.exports.jwtverify = async (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        const {jwt} = req.body
        const objectid = await JWT.verifyP(jwt, 'secret');
        const user = await User.findOne({_id:objectid});

        res.status(200).send({
            status:'susess',
            user:user
        });

    } catch (error) {
        next(error) 
    }
}
```

It also makes no sense to have all three of these:

```
router.use(errormiddelware)
router.use(usererrorFunction)
router.use(regularerrorFunction)
```

They all have the same signature so only the first one is ever going to be active.